# How do I get array.reduce() to use an expression from a function returned from within a function? [Calculator Project]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a calculator using javascript. Based on the four operators the user clicks, I would like to have my function operate() to array.reduce the result of two numbers.

My problem is that I cannot get chosenOperator () to equal what add (), or what any of the other operator functions has within their function. Therefore when I click an operator, operand, operator then equals, it returns undefined.

I realize that return add(), for example, is not returning add() function contents into chosenOperator which is why it is not working.

I have attempted to create an additional variable to equal add(). For example, letFinalOperator = add(). Then I attempted to plug in letFinalOperator into expression.reduce(letFinalOperator). I would have to click the + button twice for letFinalOperator to equal the answer in console. However with this solution I am getting the answer to equal letFinalOperator and not the add() function contents.

I would like to keep my add, subtract, multiply, divide functions and have one selected in chosenOperator() depending on what the user selects. Ultimately having my expression.reduce function evaluate the equation.

```js
let button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let screen = document.querySelector(".screen");
let decimal = document.querySelector("[data-type='decimal']");
let userOperator = document.querySelectorAll("[data-type='operator']");
let equals = document.querySelector("[data-type='equals']");

decimal.addEventListener("click", decimalDisplay);
button.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", buttonDisplay));
button.forEach(numbersClicked => numbersClicked.addEventListener("click", addToExpression));
userOperator.forEach(operator1 => operator1.addEventListener("click", chosenOperator));
equals.addEventListener("click", operate);

let tempExpression = [];
let expression = [];
let firstNumber;
let nextNumber;

function chosenOperator() {
  if (this.innerText == "+") {
    return add()
  } else if (this.innerText == "-") {
    return subtract();
  } else if (this.innerText == "*") {
    return multiply();
  } else if (this.innerText == "/") {
    return divide();
  }
}

function addToExpression() {

  tempExpression.push(parseInt(this.innerText));
  expression = tempExpression.filter(Boolean);
  firstNumber = expression[0];
  nextNumber = expression[1];

}

function decimalDisplay() {
  if (screen.innerHTML.includes('.')) {
    decimal.disabled;
  } else {
    screen.innerText += this.innerText;
  }
}


function buttonDisplay() {
  if (this.innerText != "*" &&
    this.innerText != "/" &&
    this.innerText != "+" &&
    this.innerText != "-" &&
    this.innerText != "=" &&
    this.innerText != "clear" &&
    this.innerText != "delete" &&
    this.innerText != ".") {
    screen.innerText += this.innerText;
  }
}


function add() {
  return firstNumber + nextNumber;
}

function subtract() {
  return firstNumber - nextNumber;
}

function multiply() {
  return firstNumber * nextNumber;
}

function divide() {
  return firstNumber / nextNumber;
}

function operate() {
  console.log(expression.reduce(chosenOperator))
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.screen {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>CALCULATOR</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="previous-operand"></div>
    <div class="current-operand"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" data-type="delete">delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-type="clear">clear</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" data-type="7">7</button>
    <button type="button">8</button>
    <button type="button">9</button>
    <button type="button" data-type="operator">/</button>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button">4</button>
      <button type="button">5</button>
      <button type="button">6</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="operator">*</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button">1</button>
      <button type="button">2</button>
      <button type="button">3</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="operator">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button">0</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="decimal">.</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="equals">=</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="operator">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `return add()` means 'Return the **result of calling the function "add"**'. Instead, `return add;` means 'Return a reference to the function "add"'

Comment: The return value of an event listener isn't used for anything.

Comment: So `chosenOperator` should push the operator function onto an array.

Comment: @Pointy solved my problem with chosenOperator = add - Thank you!